# Set Internet Access for VLAN + Default Gateway + DHCP Client

Tags: dhcp, switch, vlan, gateway

I have a question that make my mind so bussy. I would appreciate if anyone guide me about this. So let me explain:
Firstly consider We have bellow devices:

**Devices:**

- 2 L2 Managable Swiches
- 1 Router (act as unique Default Gatewayfor clients)
- 1 Internet ADSL Line
- 1 DHCP Server

**Diagram**:

Sorry, My Painting is not v.good. Also I cant have enough reputation for put pic here :) but this is overal design:

```
             -----------  
            |DHCP SERVER| 
             -----------
                 |
                 |                --------
       --------------------------| Router |--------ADSL LINE-(Internet)
       |                 |        --------
       |                 |
    -------            ------
    |SW#1 |           | SW#2 |
    -------            ------
       |                 |
       | VLAN 10         |  VLAN 20
       |                 |
    Cline-Group#1      Clinet-Group#2
```

.
**Hypothesis:**

- Company already have 250 User (Almost No more capacity for adding client)
- Each Client group has 250 users.
- Default Gateway IP set to 192.168.0.1/24
- DHCP IP Range: 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254 /24
- Because of huge users we decide to break broadcast traffic to increase network performance
- VLAN 10 for SW#1, and VLAN 20 for SW#2 was created as the VLANs. VLAN #1 is existed also by switch default.
- Preferred Vlan range is 192.168.0.0/24 (254 IP Per each client group)
- We don't do any other configuration for switch Interfaces.

**Goal:**

- The only main purpose is to prepare Network/Internet Access and monitoring facilities for both client groups without changing DHCP range using built-in switches capability.

**Want:**

- Our Router IP (192.168.0.1) should add as Default Gateway for VLAN.
- Each Client group Should get IP using it`s Switch.
- We shouldn't get any IP Conflicts in overall network.

// Can we get result? Whats the best switch configuration at this scenario and how can we do this. //
Also glad to find your offer for this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Because of huge users we decide to break broadcast traffic to increase network performance` - Have you even looked at the network traffic? Have you verified that there's a network performance problem and that it's being caused by broadcast traffic? Or are you redesigning and reconfiguring your network based on some unfounded, unsubstantiated idea that broadcast traffic is creating a network performance problem? Do you have any data, evidence or analysis to support this change or did you just come up with it off of the top of your head?

Comment: My point being, don't make wholesale changes to your environment to fix a problem unless you know the problem actually exists. Have you identified a broadcast traffic problem that is causing network performance problems?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your nice hint for solutions, but the thing I need is just switch configuration for working as this scenario. in fact thats why i'm here. so please focus on this issue in your comment and answers. Thanks Again for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably fairly uncommon to see VLAN's isolated by switch, but there's no reason it won't work. What you'll need to do is to set up the router with an interface/subinterface and ip address in each subnet so that it can route traffic for each subnet.

Your diagram shows a single connection from the switches to the router but you haven't shown how that connection will be made. You'll need two interfaces on your router, one connected to each switch, or you'll need an intermediate switch that will connect to both switches and to the router and then you'll need to configure subinterfaces on the router for each subnet.

Each subnet will need it's own Default Gateway, which will be the ip address of the interface/subinterface of the router that's connected to the switch for that subnet.

Make note that any traffic that does need to occur between subnets will have to be routed by the router.